# hide text with css in some contexts and avoid search engine penalty?

Tags: html, css

I am working on an illustration tool that I want to be visual to users, but accessible to screen readers and search engines.  I have the following html:

```
<span class="card">A new idea is presented to the group. </span>
<span class="spoke userOne active understands">
  <span class="node">
    <span class="label">User one </span>
    <span class="relationship">is engaged in the conversation</span>
    <span class="user"><span class="status"> and understands. </span></span>
  </span>
</span>
```

here is a link to the illustration rendering with and without css:

http://jsfiddle.net/FnBd4/

http://jsfiddle.net/FnBd4/1/

EDIT:
I've changed the question slightly based on some early responses.  I'm trying not to clutter the visual representation with the text, but still have accessible copy to both screen readers and search engines.  Right now, I'm doing this by setting the font-size to 0px for the majority of elements and I was wondering if this would result in an SEO penalty?  If so, is there an ideal way to do this (aside from using an image tag with an alt attribute)?

Comment: It's likely, yeah. Why would you ever want to use `font-size: 0px`? (Edit: ah, I see, looking at the 1st link)

Comment: its likely seen as blackhat: http://forums.seochat.com/google-optimization-7/font-size-0%3B-color-transparent%3B-bad-453971.html

Comment: @Pekka - If you look at the examples the reason is clear.  It's to not clutter the visual representation, but still have the text available to screen readers and search engines.

Comment: Using `font-size: 0px` is a poor way to hide text since many browsers are offering a minimum font-size setting.

Comment: @cimmanon - fair point.

Comment: Re the reason: yeah, I see. Not sure what the right path here is. You could replace the HTML text using Javascript, but that seems as sensible or pointless as `font-size: 0px`... or `text-color: transparent` for that matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a fan of Zeldman's hide-text css for hiding text: http://www.zeldman.com/2012/03/01/replacing-the-9999px-hack-new-image-replacement/

```
.hide-text {
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This one looks like it might be the winner... testing it out now.

Comment: I don't think this solves the fundamental problem: the OP wants to show different content to search engines and human users. For entirely legitimate purposes in his case, but how is a search engine supposed to detect that, and tell it apart from real SEO spam? If they penalize `font-size: 0px`, they are likely to penalize this technique as well.

Comment: This technique is used all over the web, I'm pretty confident you wouldn't be penalized. Another option is to use the correct alt tags for the images. Alt tags have value too.

Comment: I was looking on http://yoast.com/ (I'd say he knows what he's doing with SEO) and paying attention to the way he created his social networking links.  It looks like he was using the -9999px; approach.  What's different between his approach and zeldmans, is the visibility of the text is *necessarily* false, where in the -9999px example it's * incidentally* false because the screen isn't that large.  As Zeldman points out, however, that's a huge box and bound to cause some processor issues.

Answer (score 0):

Search Engines only analyze visible content. May you can use img-Elements with alt-Attribute.

Comment: Using image sprites in this example.  Not that it can't be done, it just gets a lot more complicated for how I'm going to start hooking this up to javascript etc.

Comment: i did not see any problem using img-Elements here

Comment: It's not a problem in that example per se, it's just that using image sprites for images rather than the background property of a span tag introduces another layer of complexity that I'd rather avoid due to time constraints.

Comment: And for the record, they are atlases and not sprites. We've all been using the wrong term. Sprites are for animations in games, based on the origin of the term. Atlases are for static elements. Thank you Udacity.

Comment: You *can* use your sprite sheet as the background of a completely transparent image.

Comment: you can go the quick and dirty way or the right way. Your decision

Comment: This is an illustration tool for a personal project, I am and have been aware of using atlases (sorry Jason), with image tags, but I'd rather flip the switch now if I could avoid an seo penalty, hence the question.  I don't want to make "perfect" the enemy of "good" in this situation and I'm clear on my reasons and who's decision it is.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [WebAIM Accessibility Article](http://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/), it is generally recommended to just move screen-reader only text far to the left - outside any browser window - and screen readers will still use it.

```
.hidden{ position:absolute; left:-10000px; top:auto; width:1px; height:1px; overflow:hidden; }
```

I also particularly like Jason Lydon's posted link for using text-indent, though it only seems to be a performance difference on old machines and devices. So take your pick!